# Providing Multiple language support

Tags: android

How can I provide multiple language support in my android app? I am working on a app, in which i have to provide six different language support,on selecting french the whole text of my app will convert in to French.

Comment: Read the Android documentation!  It's all there...first Google result - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert to a different language in my Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539215/convert-to-a-different-language-in-my-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

You basically do not put your strings in code, but put them into application resource and reference by ID. On runtime, Android simply takes your ID and returns matching string. If use changes language, different resource file is used (string ID remains across resources) so your code does not need any change.

Here is article on Android developer site you want to start with: [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

**EDIT**

You shall also read this article: [Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Here is [tutorial](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/) on the subject.

Comment: I have seen  that article already,but I didn't understood very well.Can you provide me any running tutorial or any other demo code.It will more helpful for me,because i am new in android development.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is to create a file called strings.xml in your values folder, then for each language you want to support you create another folder e.g values-sv and put your translated strings.xml file there. Then in your code only use string resources instead of hard coded references e.g

```
mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.myTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add a folder in called `values-fr` (for French) and add this under the `res` folder. In there place your `strings.xml` file with your French Strings. The Android System will first look for the values folder with the language code of the device, if this is not found it will use the default `values` folder.

Your structure should look like this:

```
res/
  values/
     strings.xml
  values-fr/
     strings.xml
```

I've written a blog post on this subject. Check it out [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/04/supporting-multiple-languages.html)